# Swift/SwiftUI error: Value of type 'EnvironmentValues' has no member 'openWindow'

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to open a new window in a swiftui macOS app. I'm quite new to Swift and SwiftUI. But it seems I need the environment variable "openWindow" to open a window. However this outputs the error.

```
Swift/SwiftUI error: Value of type 'EnvironmentValues' has no member 'openWindow'
```

Now, I've seen that I can use openURL instead. But I'm kind of curious as to why openWindow doesn't work, since it is clearly present in the documentation.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuView: View{
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow;
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct MenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuView()
    }
}
``
```

Comment: Which Xcode and macOS version are you using?  As far as I can see, the `openWindow` property has only been added in macOS 13 (beta) and iOS 16.

Comment: I'm on macOS 12.6. So that was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, everything seems to be correct, the problem is that you need to add the storekit dependency.

For solved it you need add `import StoreKit`

```swift
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

struct MenuView: View{
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow;
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct MenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuView()
    }
}
```